# Let $M \in S_n(\mathbb R)$ so that $\exists d \in \mathbb N^*, M^d=I_n$. Show that $M^2=I_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M \in S_n(\mathbb R)$ so that $\exists d \in \mathbb N^*, M^d=I_n$. Show that $M^2=I_n$. What can we say if $d$ is odd ?

What I have done so far :
$M \in S_n(\mathbb R)$ so we can write $M=P^{-1} D P$ where D is diagonal, then $D^p=I_n$. If $d$ is odd then $D=I_n$ and so $D^2=I_n$ which means that $M^2=I_n$.

I still think I must have forgotten something or done something wrong

Comment: Note that if $D = I_n$, it is not only true that $M^2 = I_n$ but also true that $M = I_n$.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you must show that $M^2 = I_n$ also holds in the case that $d$ is even

Comment: @BenGrossmann so if $d$ is odd, then $M=I_n$ ?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Why was the attempted edit rejected here?  It was spot on, changing "propriety" to "property", as is correct, in the original title.

Comment: @amWhy I suspect that OP had overwritten your edit (accidentally) by putting in an edit at the same time

Comment: It wasn't my edit, @BenGrossmann.  I saw an edit suggestion to change the two words in the suggested edit review queue, which was rejected.  I suspect you're right that the suggested edit was overwritten by the OP.  I, personally, chose to make the title more on topic.  Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Please read: [How to ask a good question on math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9003), and improve your post accordingly.

Comment: @amWhy should i put the whole problem in the title like you did when i post something where the problem is short ?

Comment: Not always; there is a character limit for titles.  But when the question/problem statement is fairly short, sure, post it as a title.  It helps identify more precisely the question, which helps potential answerers understand what the question concerns.  Try to avoid using only general terms that could be applied to hundreds of questions, e.g., don't use replications of tags in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You have $M=P^{-1}DP$ with $D$ a diagonal matrix with real entries. Because $M^d=I_n$, you deduce that $D^d=I_n$. So each coefficient $\lambda$ of the diagonal of $D$ satisfies $\lambda^d=1$, and because $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, this means that $\lambda=\pm 1$. In particular, you have $D^2=I_n$, so $M^2=I_n$.